# spring-data-mongodb equivalent of @JsonUnwrapped in Jackson

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I would like to use a composition pattern to reuse common portions of classes as I can do in Jackson with @JsonUnwrapped, without adding an extra level of structure in the mongodb document, for example:

```
class A {
  int x; int y;
}
class B { 
  @JsonUnwrapped
  A a;
}
class C { 
  @JsonUnwrapped
  A a;
}
```

So that when B or C is stored in mongodb it looks like:

```
{ x:123, y:456 }
```

instead of

```
{ a: { _class:"A", x:123, y:456 } }
```

Unfortunately, I'm not finding an appropriate annotation in [spring-data-mongodb annotations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-usage-annotations) or [core spring data annotations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/annotation/package-summary.html).  Does one exist?  I understand that this necessarily makes polymorphism of the A sub-structure impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for this has since been added in Spring Data MongoDB 3.2 with the [`@Unwrapped`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/mapping/Unwrapped.html) annotation.  This is in the reference documentation under [Unwrapped Types Mapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#unwrapped-entities.mapping).

Usage:

```java
class User {
    @Id
    String userId;

    @Unwrapped(onEmpty = Unwrapped.OnEmpty.USE_NULL) 
    UserName name;
}
```

```java
class UserName {
    String firstname;
    String lastname;
}
```

```json
{
  "_id" : "1da2ba06-3ba7",
  "firstname" : "Emma",
  "lastname" : "Frost"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data MongoDB does not evaluate Jackson annotations. The best chance to get this working is by providing a [CustomConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.custom-converters) tailored to your needs.

However there's an open ticket ([DATAMONGO-1902](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1902)) to support flattening out/read nested structures into/from the parent document you may vote for.

Comment: Thanks, hopefully others can use this definitive answer too.